# How to reset idleCounter for mouse scroll in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am using the FlexEvent.IDLE event to track if the user is idle for more than 5 min. If so, the user will be loggeg out. I am also calling a popup in my application which has a scrollable data grid. When I scroll my data grid for more than 5 min , the IDLE event is triggered, which means if I am not moving my mouse and simply using the scroll, the idleCounter goes on increasing. How to reset the idleCounter on mouse scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You use the following handler for scroll on the application:

```
protected function application1_scrollHandler(event:ScrollEvent):void
        {
            //dispatches a mouse move event to reset the idle timer
            this.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,true,false));

        }
```

You can use the following syntax to add the mouse scroll handler to the application:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
                layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                scroll="application1_scrollHandler(event)">
```